# Prevent 3rd party classloader from loading a class

Tags: java, classloader, urlclassloader

I'm invoking third party code

```
method.invoke(null, args);
```

and it has a classloader that loads a class. Is it possible that I can prevent it from loading a specific class? Also There is more than one third part program that I am invoking and I am looking for a broad solution that will just generally prevent the child classloaders from loading a specific class,
seeing as how child classloaders delegate to the parent first is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok after some plugging around I figured out a way to do this, [javaagent option](http://www.javalobby.org/java/forums/t19309.html), this is an example to intercept all incoming class files, which is what I wanted. This is commonly used in things like memory profilers.